# Use in-memory file as argument in SFTP

Tags: perl, sftp, in-memory

I need to open an SFTP connection in Perl and I need to use a dsa key file but I can't actually store the file on the hard disk for security reasons. I am trying to use Net::SFTP.

```
my $sftp = Net::SFTP->new(  
    $host, user=>"$userid",
    ssh_args => {
        identity_files => [ $pathToInMemoryKeyFile ]
    }
);
```

I think I know how to get a string represented as an in memory file handle but I don't know how to get the path of that file handle such that I can pass it in as one of the ssh_args. Does anybody have any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like you need an in-memory filesystem, then the rest is easy.  The solution would then depend on the host operating system.

Comment: You could create a named pipe and pass the name to the named pipe.

Comment: One work around would be to use an ssh-agent for authorization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've looked through the various options of doing SFTP (Net::SFTP hasn't been updated since 2005, Net::SFTP::Foreign is more up to date) and they all do key authentication via a file.

Net::SFTP is backed by Net::SSH::Perl which is a pure Perl SSH implementation.  You can do some patching to make it do what you want.  I'm going to sketch it out for you.

Patch or put a wrapper around [Net::SSH::Perl::Auth::PublicKey->authenticate](https://metacpan.org/source/TURNSTEP/Net-SSH-Perl-1.34/lib/Net/SSH/Perl/Auth/PublicKey.pm#L37) to look for a new configuration key.  Let's call it `identity_keys`.

```
sub authenticate {
    my $auth = shift;
    my $ssh = $auth->{ssh};

    my $sent = 0;
    if (my $agent = $auth->mgr->agent) {
        do {
            $sent = $auth->_auth_agent;
        } until $sent || $agent->num_left <= 0;
    }
    return $sent if $sent;

    ##### This is the new bit which tries any keys passed in. ######
    my $ik = $ssh->config->get('identity_keys') || [];
    for my $key (@$ik) {
        return 1 if $auth->_auth_key($key);
    }

    my $if = $ssh->config->get('identity_files') || [];
    my $idx = $auth->{_identity_idx} || 0;
    for my $f (@$if[$idx..$#$if]) {
        $auth->{_identity_idx}++;
        return 1 if $auth->_auth_identity($f);
    }
}
```

`auth_key` would be a copy of `_auth_identity` but calling Net::SSH::Perl::Key->read_private_key which would be the guts of [Net::SSH::Perl::Key->read_private_pem](https://metacpan.org/source/TURNSTEP/Net-SSH-Perl-1.34/lib/Net/SSH/Perl/Key.pm#L69) minus opening and reading the key from a file.  `read_private_pem` would then be gutted to use `read_private_key`.

Alternatively, use an ssh-agent.  It holds the decrypted private key in memory, so you can immediately wipe it from the disk.

Comment: I ended up moving to Net::SFTP::Foreign and using a passphrase so that the key file could be stored on disk encrypted. Thanks for your detailed answer!!